# libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found on ubuntu virtual box with SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to learn SDL using C++. I wrote a simple C++ program as mentioned below on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Virtual box guest Operating System (Host : Mac).

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled this program using "g++ test.cpp -L/usr/lib -lSDL2", it compiled without any errors and generated executable program. But when I ran a.out, it is giving following errors.

```
pci id for fd 5: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
```

Can any one please let me know how to fix this issue?

Comment: This error is not about your code, rather it is about OpenGL lib and dri lib. Have you installed the relevant dri libs needed by your OpenGL lib?